# Ruby on Rails cannot find Initializer?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to deploy an app to a fresh Ubuntu 10 installation using Passenger 2.2.15, Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7, and Apache 2.2.14. However, even with a default rails app (`sudo rails defaultapp`), I am receiving the following error: "no such file to load -- initializer".

I'm not sure which files you might need copies of in order to diagnose this problem, so I'll copy a few here and hope that it will help.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

-RM

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/appname/public
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>



    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf**

```
<IfModule passenger_module>
   PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15
   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
</IfModule>
```

**/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load**

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails was not installed into /appname/vendor/rails, I installed it by running `sudo rake rails:freeze:edge RELEASE=2.3.5` and then changing permissions accordingly. It is disturbing that Ubuntu requires sudo to do everything with Rails and thus requires constant permissions manipulation.

Additionally, this resulted in another error: **can't activate rack (= 1.2.1, runtime) for [], already activated rack-1.0.1 for []**, which I am still working on.